# Embedding ogg audio livestream to wix page

Tags: html, live-streaming, ogg

I'm hosting on wix and want to embed a simple audio player to play a livestream. I have tested the code in w3schools and the audio plays. However, when viewing the wix site with the same code embedded, the player loads with a runtime of 0:00 and won't play, even when clicked.

I can only assume there is a conflict with the iframe wix runs the code in.

The live page is at https://www.joetimothycoleman.com/bewilderments-22

Any solutions welcome!

```
<html>
    <Head>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <audio controls autoplay>
      <source src="http://locus.creacast.com:9001/slawica_puszcza_zielonka.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
    
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me when I click it on your website.

Comment: the audio player? May I ask your browser, as I can't get it to work in edge or chrome

Comment: Firefox. It looks like Chrome may not support long (large) OGG files. There a couple Google links that suggest others have the same issue.

Comment: It's strange because like I say in the original post, the audio player works in both edge and chrome when using the w3schools code tester, just not in the wix iframe embed. Thanks for your clarification